# Optional Characters, Numbers, Symbols regex

Tags: regex

The regex task that I am trying to achieve is pretty simple. A string can contain one of the following:

- alphabet plus numbers
- alphabet plus numbers plus symbols
- alphabet plus symbols

I have been able to achieve the first two points but I am struggling to get the last one.

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).{7,}$/
```

Strings that should match are as followed:

- test123
- test123@#][
- test@#;[-=

Please note that for the last scenario when I say `alphabet plus symbols`. I'd like it to match any symbols. I did alternatively try:

`/(.*).{7}/`

And this did not work. Reason being because that means an individual could enter just letters. So in order for the regex to satisfy it **needs** to be one of the following above as stated.

Comment: My friend, by "plus" do you mean, "necessarily followed by"? And _must_ there be alphabetical characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sense that by "plus" you mean "then", so this should do it:

```
^(?=.{7,})[a-zA-Z]+(?!$)[0-9]*[^a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

This regex requires that if numbers and symbols are present, that number precede symbols.

Here "symbol" is defined as any character *not* a letter or number, you may want to instead list the characters that are "symbols", eg `[@%#()*]`

A negative look ahead is used to require that at least some characters must follow the letters.

Comment: Is there a way I can limit this by 7 characters? I did try and do {7, } just before the dollar ($)

Comment: Limit of 7 added using a look ahead anchored at start of input - see edit

Comment: With this edit in place this means that the regex does not match anything if the string > 7. I was wrong in saying "limit" what is there a way you can restrict the regex so the minimum of characters entered is 7 sorry.

Comment: Yes - just add a comma after the 7 (meaning "7 *or more*"). Without an upper limit, you cn also remove the $ end-of-input anchors. See edit

Comment: I noticed something with the regex. For some reason you can enter just 7 letters and the regex will pass. This shouldn't be the case because the regex should **require** at least a symbol or number or symbols and numbers

Comment: Put a `$` at the end (see edit). These subtle issues vary between languages/tools. You really should tag your question with the language.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on my interpretation, this might work:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+[^a-zA-Z]+$/
```

Comment: `[^\w]` will exclude numbers

Comment: no. It won't as `|` will be taken as or in the current context

Comment: @AmitJoki Thanks mate. I've had a long break, maybe I should do a refresher before answering these things.

Comment: Will accept in 5minutes as i can't accept it yet. But I like yours because it is concise, also the other one seems to match anything as i enter any value.

Comment: but this will allow "abc@2" - ie "alphabet symbol number", which is not allowed

Comment: @Bohemian Yes, true. There were quite a few ambiguities to contend with.